# How to correctly pass the data array to the server and to the download link?

Tags: flask

I need to implement the ability to download an unload from a database in xlsx format.

The user can choose which columns to unload (columns variable) and use a filter on several columns - variables: year, station, indicators.

Now, when you click the download button, an empty table is downloaded to excel, with the headers written in worksheet.append. Tell me, please, what's wrong? As I understand it, you need to somehow rewrite the code so that the headers are not immediately set explicitly, but are taken based on the user's choice. Other than that, I have no idea what could be wrong.

in the html file I attach how the table and headers + the link itself are processed, otherwise the classic select multiple is used.

**html**

```
<tbody class="table-hover">

<table class="table-fill">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for column in columns %}
      <th>{{ column }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>

{% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
      {% for column in columns %}
      <td>{{ row[loop.index0] }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<a href = "{{url_for('download', columns = request.args.getlist('columns'), year = request.args.getlist('year'), indicators=request.args.getlist('indicators'), station=request.args.getlist('station'))}}">download</a>
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/download", methods=["GET","POST"])
def download():
    if request.method == "GET":
        year = request.form.getlist("year")
        year = [int(i) for i in request.form.getlist("year") if i.isdigit()]
        station = request.form.getlist("station")
        station = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("station")]
        indicators = request.form.getlist("indicators")
        indicators = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("indicators")]
        columns = request.form.getlist("columns")
        columns = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("columns")]
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT {} FROM fact_indicators WHERE fact_year = ANY(%s) AND fact_indicators = ANY(%s) AND fact_station_name = ANY(%s);"
                    .format(",".join(["\"{}\"".format(c) for c in columns])),(year, indicators, station))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close
        filename = "fact_T2.xlsx"
        filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
        worksheet.append([year, station, january, fabruary, may, 1kv, 2kv, 3kv, 4kv])
        for row in rows:
            worksheet.append(list(row))           
        workbook.save(filepath)
        return send_from_directory(os.path.dirname(__file__),  path=filename, as_attachment=True)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```